# Filter AuroraMysql slow query log file by specific queries

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, percona, mysql-slow-query-log, amazon-aurora

I downloaded the slow query log file from Aurora Mysql. I want to playback these queries but separate them to just writes and reads. So a tool to extract only selects, or Inserts+Updates would be nice

Comment: For "playback" it might be better to capture the "general log".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! we can use `pt-query-digest`

```
pt-query-digest mysql-slowquery.log --no-report --output slowlog --filter '$event->{fingerprint} =~ m/^insert|^update/' > writes-only.log
```